# Helmchart values yaml override with helmfile

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, helmfile, helm3

I try to my custom chart's values.yaml change with overridevalue.yaml to override values. However when I install the chart with helm repo add command and try to reach values yaml it throws me "values.yaml does not exist in ".".

[image]

Comment: Does changing `values.yaml` to `./values.yaml` fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Helm automatically uses values.yaml file from chart's root directory.

you can pass additional values or override existing ones by passing the file during installation:

```
$ helm install -f override_values.yaml app ./app
```

you can pass multiple `-f <values_yaml> .. ..`. The priority will be given to the last (right-most) file specified for overriding existing values.